# Is this going to be safe in the rain?

Tags: electrical, water, rain

Is this going to be safe in the rain?The contractor left it like this & the property manager doesn’t care. It’s directly under my bedroom window, so I’m a bit concerned.[image: left photo is what they did to run an extension cord to the 5th floor right photo is how they left it]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not safe. NEC requires all conductors to be installed in an appropriate enclosure or totally removed. I suppose I should give you NEC Article 110.3 for the reference that does not allow what your picture is showing.

You might want to quote this to your property manager and contractor.

Needless to say this is an unsafe situation and you might mention that they have a certain amount of liability if in fact some one is injured because of their lack of action. I am not sure if you are dealing with the installer or directly with the owner of the contracting firm that left it that way. Usually the owner is a lot more concerned than there employees. If that doesn't work I advise you to contact your AHJ have have them deal with the problem.

Stay safe and good luck.

Comment: Also, water will enter that conduit and end up... where?

Comment: That’s what I thought!!